# How to call/use a function inside an object?

Tags: javascript

I want to call a function or even create one in an object map-area.

How does it properly work? This is what I got. Doesn’t work though…

```
var _images = {
    test: {
        path: 'test.jpg',
        areas: [{
            coords: '211,38,238,60',
            text: 'let me test it',
            //onclick: .... ?
            obj = function() {
                this.hello = function hello() {}
                alert("Hello");
            }
        }]
    },
}
var asdf = new obj();
asdf.hello();
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Are you getting any error?

Comment: Nothing happens ^^ I need to declare the function on onclick, isn't it?

Comment: What is this *supposed* to do...?!

Comment: When you click on the area it should alert the message

Comment: Click on what area?

Comment: areas is an array of objects, and you broke it by using `obj = function...`, you should just use `obj: function...`. And more, the `new obj()` part has no meaning...

Comment: This by itself won't do any such thing. No, in the *smaller view*... what's the `obj = function ...` *inside* an object literal supposed to do, especially when you later do `new obj()` directly...?!

Comment: Hmm, how can I call it from onclick ? like this ?  https://jsfiddle.net/nyxg8s53/3/

Comment: @Emloy No one has any idea what the heck you're talking about.

Comment: I have many  map areas with coordinates declared in an object. Just wanted to call a function when you click on these areas

Answer (score 1):

Javascript object function is ":" not "=" ! You can call new instance object as their paths as you wanted ... like below

```
var _images = {
  test: {
    path: 'test.jpg',
    areas: [{
      coords: '211,38,238,60',
      text: 'let me test it',
      //onclick: .... ?
      obj : function() {
        this.hello = function hello() {}
        alert("Hello");
      }

    }]
  },
}
var asdf = new _images.test.areas[0].obj();
asdf.hello();
```

Comment: But how can I call it when I click on the coords: '211,38,238,60',  ?

Comment: If you want to click , must append to html .How(Where) do you click on the coords ?

Comment: My html file only calls the js file.  I created with DOM-Elements the images and map areas.

Answer (score -2):

对象属性应该用`:`

```
var _images = {
    test: {
        path: 'test.jpg',
        areas: {
            coords: '211,38,238,60',
            text: 'let me test it',
            //onclick: .... ?
            obj:function() {
                this.hello = function hello() {};
                console.log('hello')
            }

        }
    }
};

var asdf = new _images.test.areas.obj();
asdf.hello();
```

Comment: You should write in English ! This is not local site